# How to set app.config value using javascript in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

Can anybody help me...I already google for almost 3 hours,but no solution found...How to set app.config value using javascript in C#?? Thanks...

Comment: question makes no sense.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "using javascript in c#"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to edit app.Config and you can't

App.config is serverside and javascript is clientside

Answer (score 1):

If you are crazy you might beable to use javascript and manipulate the app.config as if it is just plain xml

[XML string manipulation in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084476/xml-string-manipulation-in-js)

Madness though.

Even manipulating the config file through c# isn't the best idea. app.config is for initial setup - values that won't change during the lifetime of the app.

2nd answer here [Is switching app.config at runtime possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436700/is-switching-app-config-at-runtime-possible) gives further details / reasons for not meddling